# window.open from Chrome to IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am working on a MVC application that needs to open a specific URL in Internet Explorer. It works fine when the user is using IE but if the user is using Chrome or Mozilla, window.open uses that browser, as expected since it is most likely the default browser.

Is there any way to force window.open to use IE? The page has to be opened in IE and isn't an option to use another browser.

If there isn't any way to do it using window.open, then is it possible to do another way?

Comment: window.open will always open a window of the same browser. There is no way, from chrome you can open up ie or vice verse.

Comment: Faced a similar problem. Found this as the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531374/open-internet-explorer-from-chrome-using-a-protocol-handler-ieurl/41749105#41749105

Comment: Regardless of the purpose, just don't.

Answer (score 1):

It's called [registering an application to a URI scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx) think you probably need to rethink the behavior of the app

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to open it in new tab then you can use `windows.location.href("url")`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this because that means you are in control of the user's device. There is no way to do this from the browser.