# Open Hyperlink in different browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can we open the hyperlink in Internet Explorer instead of opening in the same browser (chrome in my case) by HTML, Javascript?

Comment: No.............

Comment: It'd be interesting why you would want to do that.

Comment: No - You cannot, because of security reasons. Why do you need to do that ?

Comment: Well actually.... If the user has handlers set up for custom protocols, it could happen. For example mailto: is the most famous example. Spotify has a custom protocol handler to launch Spotify from the browser. Dropbox app also installs some hack on your browser. I'm sure you could use a href like ie:Google.com and it'll open in ie if the user set up the appropriate handler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Internet Explorer from Chrome using a protocol handler (ie:url)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531374/open-internet-explorer-from-chrome-using-a-protocol-handler-ieurl)

Answer (score 2):

If the user has handlers set up for custom protocols, it could happen. For example mailto: is the most famous example. Spotify has a custom protocol handler to launch Spotify from the browser. Dropbox app also installs some hack on your browser. I'm sure you could use a href like ie:Google.com and it'll open in ie if the user set up the appropriate handler.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible because no one browser can't open something from your computer, it's forbidden.