# Passing parameter(s) with URL through custom protocol handler (Chrome to IE)

Tags: javascript, html, batch-file, cmd, registry

I have followed the instructions in [this Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531374/open-internet-explorer-from-chrome-using-a-protocol-handler-ieurl) to create a custom protocol handler in Windows 7 that will open any URL prefixed with "ie:" in Internet Explorer. As explained in [Microsofts post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)) on custom protocol handlers there are issues with how special character are treated, and thus problems passing parameters with URLs.

In the [linked thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531374/open-internet-explorer-from-chrome-using-a-protocol-handler-ieurl) there is a post by Saurabh which suggests creating a local html file with a script that correctly parses the URL and then redirects to this new updated URL. I haven't gotten this to work.

What works:

- The protocol handler can open custom URLs (ie:https://www.google.se, ie:file:///C:/ieRedirect.html) from external programs in Internet Explorer.
- Local files opened with the protocol can launch **hardcoded** URLs containing parameters (not very useful, see code below)

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   IE Redirect
  </title>
  <script>
   function testOpenURL(){
    window.open('https://www.google.se/search?q=stackoverflow', '_self');
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="testOpenURL()">

 </body>
</html>
```

Questions:

- Is there a way to get Saurabh's workaround to work and pass one or more parameters with the URL?
- Is there another method to pass parameters through a custom protocol handler?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. You can find my reg file below.

```html
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie]
"URL Protocol"="\"\""
@="\"URL:IE Protocol\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\DefaultIcon]
@="\"iexplore.exe,1\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /C set myvar=%1 & call set myvar=%%myvar:ie:=%% & call start /separate iexplore %%myvar%% & exit"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also failed modifying the protocol sufix on command string vaue, so I've get one different way to solve this problem:

- Create a page on your server (e.g.  `http: //<your.domain>/redirect/index.php`) like this:

```
<?php
   $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : die('Access denied');
   $url = str_replace('ie', 'http', $url);
   header('Location: ' . $url);
   die();
?>
```

- Set the `command` key value as `"iexplore.exe" "http://<your.domain>/redirect?url=%1"`