# Is there a way to hide "Open Windows Command Processor" prompt from registry protocol handler?

Tags: .net, windows, internet-explorer, registry, custom-protocol

I have created a custom protocol handler to redirect url from chrome to ie. I followed this link and achieved it - [Open Internet Explorer from Chrome using a protocol handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531374/open-internet-explorer-from-chrome-using-a-protocol-handler-ieurl#answer-41749105)

I have a button in a page and on click user will be redirected to IE from Chrome but getting "Open Windows Command Processor" prompt all the time. It's really annoying for the user to click on this prompt each time.

So Is there a way to get rid of/hide this prompt?

I tried to set /MIN in the reg file but it doesn't help me.

Any help would be more helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced the problem on my side, but unfortunately not found a way to get rid of/hide this prompt.

In my opinion, I'm not suggesting you hide this prompt, because this prompt could remind us some malware programs wants to open the Windows command, then modify the registry or change the windows setting. It could protect our computer. More detail information, you could check [this article](https://appuals.com/fix-windows-command-processor-startup-windows-10/).