# can i set a Windows.print from chrome to a IE modal?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute a windows.print () using js from a chrome browser to open a modal in IE and execute that function. It's possible?

This is executed from the web using a button that calls this function.

Here I draw my idea

[image: image idea]

Comment: I doubt it very much. A browser has very limited access to the underlying operating system

Comment: I would certainly hope not.

Comment: @JaromandaX The browser itself has the same access to the OS as any other software installed, but it does not give web developers this access (for good)

Comment: @Fitzi - yes, I meant a web page doesn't have such access

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: This is generally not possible

Slightly less short answer: If you control the machine(s) this should work on, you can do something similar (no modal, but an IE window/tab) with a custom protocol handler. See here: [Open Internet Explorer from Chrome using a protocol handler (ie:url)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531374/open-internet-explorer-from-chrome-using-a-protocol-handler-ieurl)

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers