# How can I pass cookie from Chrome to IE launched through custom protocol handler?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, cookies, custom-protocol

I have set up a custom protocol for Internet Explorer by following this thread ([Open Internet Explorer from Chrome using a protocol handler (ie:url)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531374/open-internet-explorer-from-chrome-using-a-protocol-handler-ieurl/41749105#41749105)), and I can launch the IE window by `window.open('ie:https://****')` to show the new page. However, this page requires a cookie that is stored in Chrome, is there any way to pass the cookie to IE during the way, without relying on any extension?

Comment: it is not possible to pass cookies from Chrome to IE through the custom protocol handler. Does the suggestion I provided you in the answer to help you to get the answer for your question? If yes, you can try to accept the answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my search results, it is not possible to pass cookies from Chrome to IE through the custom protocol handler.

Browsers do not have this feature to share the cookie with other browsers.

Cookies meant to be used for that specific browser on which it is created.

Below are the helpful threads.

1. [Is it possible for one browser to read/write cookies of another one?](https://superuser.com/questions/775416/is-it-possible-for-one-browser-to-read-write-cookies-of-another-one)
2. [Synchronize Cookies Between Browsers](https://superuser.com/questions/271710/synchronize-cookies-between-browsers)

Comment: Marked this as answer as I can't find the possible solution after searching at my best, and this answer gives extra information in the community. Thanks Deepak.